# I want to verify menu bar tabs of a site instead of clicking them

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I want to verify menu bar tabs in a site to confirm that the tabs names are exactly the same names that they should be and print them.
I tried to do that using `linkText()` but I don't know how to verify them.

```
public class Automate2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.toolsqa.com/");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();

  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Home"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try any of the Assert mentioned in the code.However my code has run on chrome not Firefox but assert methods are same.

```
package SeleniumPractice;

import java.io.File;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class TestSOF {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File filepath=new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Executables\\chromedriver.exe" );
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", filepath.getAbsolutePath());
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.toolsqa.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);     
        Assert.assertEquals("HOME",wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".menu-text"))).getText());
        Assert.assertTrue(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".menu-text"))).isDisplayed());

        System.out.println("Pass");


    }

}
```

Please let me know if the code work.